# Sigma Additivity of Power set

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

Let $\left\{x_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of distinct points in $M$ and $\left\{m_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of positive numbers with
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} m_{k}<\infty
$$
For each subset $A \subset M$ we define $\mu(A)$ with.
$$
\mu(A)=\sum_{\left\{k: x_{k} \in A\right\}} m_{k}
$$
I would like to see why $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive on the power set $\mathcal{P}(M)$.

My thoughts are that $A \subset M \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)\subset \mathcal{P}(M)$
and as $A$ is a disjoint union we have additivity so we just have to put $n \rightarrow \infty$ and this finishes the proof but that seems too easy and maybe even totally wrong. Has anyone an idea of proving this statement? Thanks for advice in advance.

Comment: There's definitely more to it than that. Perhaps you should start by writing out what "$\sigma$-addivive on $\mathcal P(M)$" means, concretely. You will find you need to care about more than one $A$ at a time.

Comment: It is not a matter of working with one $A\subseteq M$. You must prove that for disjoint $A_1,A_2,\dots\subseteq M$ we have: $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must prove that for disjoint $A_1,A_2,\dots\subseteq M$ we have: $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)$$

---

Observe that: $$\mu\left(A\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}m_{k}1_{A}\left(x_{k}\right)$$

Now for $n=1,2,3,\dots$ let $A_{n}\subseteq M$ be disjoint subsets of $M$ and let $A:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$.

Then: $$1_{A}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1_{A_{n}}$$
so that:

$$\mu\left(A\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}m_{k}1_{A}\left(x_{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}m_{k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1_{A_{n}}\left(x_{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}m_{k}1_{A_{n}}\left(x_{k}\right)=$$$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}m_{k}1_{A_{n}}\left(x_{k}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu\left(A_{n}\right)$$

Comment: Why can you represent the indicator function of A as a sum of indicator functions of subsets of A?

Comment: Because the $A_n$ are disjoint and $A$ is their union. In general: $$1_{A\cup B}=1_A+1_B-1_{A\cap B}$$ and this will result in:  $$1_{A\cup B}=1_A+1_B$$ if $A\cap B=\varnothing$. This also works for countable unions of disjoints.